# Swift kill view controller when performing segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have View Controller (in ex. B) with AVPlayer for playing music. The problem is, I open this View Controller from another (in ex. A) VC by performing segue and passing the playlist object (songs list). Everything is working pretty fine for the first time, but when I perform segue again (not a unwind segue) to A VC, somehow (I believe) B VC still has the old values and is in the memory (?). And when I tap on another playlist and perform segue to B VC it starts playing music from the new playlist and somehow music starts playing from the old playlist and I get two AVPlayers which I cannot even kill. And if I repeat this step, the number of AVPlayers keeps increasing.

So, the question is (it's not about my code, so no need for that):

Does performing the segue kills the last VC instance(?) ?

If not, how should I present new VC and pass variables to it?

Comment: Um, why are performing a new segue? Why don't you unwind?

Comment: agree with user @avismara, recommended way to navigate back `dismis` and `pop`.

Comment: When you make segue from A to B, you don't kill it. A still remains in the stack. If you want to go from B to A, you are supposed to navigate back using unwind segue. If you want to from A to B by killing A, then you're supposed to have a custom container view which does that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never thought this would warrant a separate answer; thought this could be easily answered in comments. But I can't let this question exist with an answer provided by Amar here. It's wrong and doesn't make sense at all in the context.

That said, to answer your question, the reason why the instances aren't being killed because, the way you are doing -- performing segues on top of view controllers, builds up a stack that looks something like this:

> A -> B -> A -> B -> A -> B

If you remember your Stack data structure, this is same as "pushing" elements onto a "stack of view controllers". This design "requires" all the instances of view controllers to remain in the memory. This explains why the music won't stop.

What kills `B`? Well, simply put "pop"ping the instance of `B` from this "stack", kills it.

You have :

> A

You are now pushing `B` :

> A -> B

Now if you want to go back to `B`. You pop `B`. Now the stack looks like this.

> A

`B` is history. Notice how in the previous case of continuously pushing, `B` is alive and singing.

There are a couple of ways of popping a view controller from this stack in iOS. There are APIs like `popViewController(:animated:)` if you are building this on `UINavigationController`. There is `dismissViewController(:animated:completion:)` if you are modally presenting view controllers. And of course, there is the stated unwind segues help you pop the view controller.

Answer (score -1):

you should nil player controller object nil or make player object week reference with view controller. or you can check if vc instance created every time new or not

```
import UIKit

var instanceCount: Int = 0 //

class MayBeAClassHere { 
}

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    var inViewController = instanceCount 
    inViewController++ // inViewController is a brand new COPY
    println(inViewController) // print  1
    println(instanceCount) // print 0
}
}
```